# Dynamic Columns Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

How can i add several columns if i add the "click here to add transportation field" like i want to add driver, contact number etc.... Once you click the modal, it will show you some options on what field to add. Please check the code link that I've made. here's also my codes below. Please check also the image here [image: CHECK THIS IMAGE]

CHECK THIS LINK [https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-hj5nur?file=app/app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-gpwwac?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef < any > ) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
}

initGroup() {
  let rows = this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  rows.push(this.fb.group({
    description: [null, Validators.required],
    pickup_area: [null, Validators.required],
    pickup_time: [null, Validators.required],
    sign_board: [null, Validators.required],
    driver: [null],
    contact_number: [null],
    transportation_unit: [null],
    special_instructions: [null],
  }))
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, you're trying to dynamically add  another `formControl` to a `formGroup` in a `formArray`. Is that right?

Comment: @SiddAjmera. Yes. Youre right

Comment: What exactly is the modal expected to do again?

Comment: @SiddAjmera. You have to select from the list in the modal what fields you want to add. For example if you select driver in the modal. It would add a new column named driver.

Comment: Okay. So the modal `input`s should be check boxes instead.

Comment: @SiddAjmera. Checkbox is ok. Yes

Comment: @SiddAjmera. Is this ok with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180335/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-gray-singh).

Comment: @SiddAjmera. Hello bro

Comment: Would you please consider creating a Bounty for this?

Comment: @SiddAjmera. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the edited stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-d3xsnf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

this link contains validation too :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-ytiiqp?file=app/custom-required-validator.ts

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for your effort! By the way, if driver, contact number etc... is selected from the modal. Then it should be required also. Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-hthkyc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new `FormGroup` for the modal fields and then use this form's `value` to show or hide those specific fields from the main `form`

Also, since you're already creating those fields in the main form but assigning them `undefined`, it won't matter if they're actually present on the form or not if the form's value is all you care about.

So following these steps would fix your issue:

**First:** Create a new FormGroup for your Modal

```
this.fieldSelectionForm = this.fb.group({
  driver: [true],
  contact_number: [true],
  transportation_unit: [true],
  special_instructions: [true]
});
```

**Second:** Create a variable on the class for configuring what needs to be visible/hidden from the main form:

```
formControlsVisibilityConfig;
```

**Third:** Read the value of the modal form on it's submission and assign it to `formControlsVisibilityConfig`. Also, hide the modal:

```
onFormSubmit() {
  console.log(this.fieldSelectionForm.value);
  this.formControlsVisibilityConfig = this.fieldSelectionForm.value
  this.modalRef.hide();
}
```

**Fourth:** Bind the form to the template:

```
<h3>Transportation
    <button type="button" (click)="openModal(add)"> Click Here to add Transportation Fields</button>
</h3>
<br>
<form [formGroup]="addForm">
    <div formArrayName="rows">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Pick Up Area</th>
                    <th>Pick Up Time</th>
                    <th>Sign Board</th>
          <th *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.driver">Driver</th>
                    <th *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.contact_number">Contact Number</th>
                    <th *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.transportation_unit">Transportation Unit</th>
                    <th *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.special_instructions">Special Instructions</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of addForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="pickup_area">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="pickup_time">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="sign_board">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.driver">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="driver">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.contact_number">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="contact_number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.transportation_unit">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="transportation_unit">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="formControlsVisibilityConfig?.special_instructions">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="special_instructions">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" 
              class="btn btn-square btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" 
              (click)="onDeleteRow(i)"><i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i> Remove
            </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" (click)="initGroup()"> Add Row</button>
    </div>
</form>



<ng-template #add>
    <div role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
        <div class="login-card-modal">
            <form 
        class="md-float-material" 
        [formGroup]="fieldSelectionForm"
        (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
                <div class="auth-box">
                    <div class="row m-b-0">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3 class="text-center">Add Fields</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            Driver
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="driver">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            Contact number
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="contact_number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            Transportation Unit
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="transportation_unit">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            Special Instructions
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="special_instructions">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-reactive-forms-dynamic-fields?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! By the way, if driver, contact nunber etc... is selected from the modal. Then it should be required also. Please edit. Thank you

Comment: Hello. Did you get it?

Comment: It's really hard to achieve I guess. You might consider looking for alternatives.

Comment: @Joseph, thanks a lot for that. Are you facing the same issue? Did you find any way around it?